# balancing rsync in directories

Tags: shell, rsync

I need to rsync a remote directory to a local server,
balancing file in 4 destination directory (related to 4 disk mounts).

tips?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "balancing", and (imo) move this to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` has no option to run a script before or after a download to create a new filename.

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Make sure the source files are in different directories, and mount the filesystems on the destination accordingly.
2. Download the files into one place and then distribute them from there.
3. Download the files into a different filesystem every day
4. Use a balancing filesystem (RAID5, filesystems for clusters, btrfs or ceph)